# wget post file. data body is undefined

Tags: wget

I don't have curl installed and don't want it. The receiving servers data body is `undefined` when I try to post my file contents (my file is not blank, it has a json object in it)

(Google is not helping)

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
wget --timeout=10 --tries=1 --post-file "/home/user/temp.json" https://address.com:123
```

Answer (score 0):

You provided virtually no data for us to replicate the problem. *Maybe* the problem is in what I emphasized in the following fragment of the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html#HTTP-Options):

> ```
> --post-data=string
> --post-file=file
> ```
>
> Use POST as the method for all HTTP requests and send the specified data in the request body. `--post-data` sends string as data, whereas `--post-file` sends the contents of file. Other than that, they work in exactly the same way. **In particular, they both expect content of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, with percent-encoding for special characters;** the only difference is that one expects its content as a command-line parameter and the other accepts its content from a file. **In particular, `--post-file` is not for transmitting files as form attachments**: those must appear as `key=value` data (with appropriate percent-coding) just like everything else. […]
>
> Please note that wget does not require the content to be of the form `key1=value1&key2=value2`, and neither does it test for it. **Wget will simply transmit whatever data is provided to it. Most servers however expect the POST data to be in the above format when processing HTML Forms.**
>
> […]